# Why can I still log in via SSH (PAM Auth) while `shutdown -k` is active?

Tags: ssh, login, shutdown, pam

Pretty straight-forward. Does SSH ignore the `nologin` file created by `shutdown -k TIME`?

Using PAM Auth to sync password database to users; if that makes a difference.

Comment: What do you expect from shutdown -k? On Linux the man page says:

-k     Don't really shutdown; only send the warning messages to everybody.

Comment: Yeah I guess the point is to not allow users to login anymore. But it seems like on my system, via SSH, they still can login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems, shutdown -k doesn't actually shutdown.  Also shutdown ONLY creates the nologin file if you specify a shutdown time that is in the future (not now).

Comment: Yeah I know. But it seems like the SSHD or it's AUTH is ignoring **nologin** because I still have people login in.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused, did you touch that file?  Or you did a shutdown now?  shutdown -k won't create the file so it isn't there for sshd to ignore.

Comment: Ignore my first comment. Because as @polynomial said, only `shutdown` creates the `nologin` file. And to all, sorry for taking so long to mark this one **Answered**.